# Laravel Eloquent firstOrCreate doesn't work properly

Tags: laravel, eloquent, mass-assignment

I'm used to it but today this problem makes me weak..;;

```
class Market {
    // ..
    public function ttl()
    {
        return $this->ttlRelation()->firstOrCreate(
            ['market_id' => $this->id],
            ['tier' => 0, 'direction'=>0]
        );
    }
}
```

The `Market` model has one TTL model. I know that `firstOrCreate` method finds an item as first given array and if it doesn't exists create a new one as persist, returns it.

Besides, its mass-assignment so I filled up `$fillable` property on ttl model..

```
class TradingTacticalLayer extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['direction', 'tier'];
}
```

..and I'm getting `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'direction' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into "trading_tactical_layer_test" ("tier", "market_id") values (0, 1))` message. I cannot understand why this method won't filled up insert field list proper way. I expect, if I edit `$fillable` property as `['direction']`, SQL would implode ("direction") as insert field and it doesn't.

In general, from my experience, I just set those fields as nullable or manually set a default value. At this time, I want to know why this weird happens and what am I doing wrong.

Comment: verify that the error is related to the code you posted.

Comment: did you try `php artisan optimize:clear` ?

Comment: I believe `optimize:clear` somehow solve the problem. If you add answer, I will check yours. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, probably, `optimize:clear` solve the problem.

I still don't know what makes this error but if you experience mismatch between `$fillable` property and inserting field list, `optimize:clear` is an option anyway..