# Laravel Eloquent updateOrCreate doesn't work properly

Tags: laravel

I once wrote probably same question last time and I'm back..

[Laravel Eloquent firstOrCreate doesn't work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70493014/laravel-eloquent-firstorcreate-doesnt-work-properly)

On the last question, I found that `fillable` property filters update field manifest. So, if you want to update a table based on `fieldA` and `fieldB`, then your code might be..

```
$modelOrRelation->updateOrCreate(
    ['fieldA' => 'a', 'fieldB' => 'b'], ['otherfields' => 'update value']
);
```

and you MUST specify those fields on `fillable` property. `$fillable = ['fieldA', 'fieldB', ...]`

This is what I know about `firstOrCreate` and `updateOrCreate`.

At this time, following code generate many same rows. It looks like, the first parameter `['candle_date_time_kst']` do nothing..

```
// candleRelation is hasMany relation..
$candleRelation = $market->candles($period);

$created = $created->add($candleRelation->updateOrCreate(
    [
        'candle_date_time_kst' => $time,
    ],
    $item
));
```

This creates many same `candle_date_time_kst` value rows. At this time, `fillable` property already filled target fields.

What else do I miss?

Is `updateOrCreate` should not trust? I didn't think so.. There are something I miss... any insight?

---

#220114 update

So, I do my homework..

Using `DB::getQueryLog()`, I get this query..

[image]

It looks like, `updateOrCreate()` remembers the last update value. Then if I reuse same eloquent relation object for another `updateOrCreate()`, method use last update parameter again. It makes `and` clause, so return record is none..

So, I use `newQuery()` method for initialize query bindings.

```
$created->add($candleRelation->newQuery()->updateOrCreate(
    [
        'candle_date_time_kst' => $time
    ],
    $item
));
```

#220114

Unfortunately, retest reveals `newQuery()` actually not helping..

I tried `$relation->newModelInstance()` and getting same bindings.

What I trying to do is getting same parent binding without anything else. .. anyone knows?

---

Based on binding, when I get relation model I can get clean binding also. So I just do below..

```
$created->add($market->candles($period)->updateOrCreate(
    [
        'candle_date_time_kst' => $item['candle_date_time_kst']
    ],
    $item
));
```

Only change is `$candleRelation` to `$market->candles($period)`.

On each attempt, new relation instance produce so binding problem won't even exists.

.... I'm mad.

Answer (score 0):

you need to supply an array in the format
[ column => value, ... ]  not [ value ]

Comment: oh my mistake.. I edit my question..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a time ago. And the [UpdateOrInsert](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#update-or-insert) method solved it.
Unfortunately, this method is Query Builder, not eloquent. But to achieve this result that was the only really working solution to me.

The issue for only happened when I tried to use more than 1 column on where clause, like in your example.